# How to dismiss a bootstrap alert message via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to close the alert message by jQuery rather than `data-dismiss="alert"`

I am using `$("div.alert").alert();`, but it seems not working.

My example: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9JLSW/)

Comment: where is the eventHandler for the button, which does the closing? why can't you do the `data-dismiss="alert"`-way?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, the [document](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts) said alert message could be dismissed via javascript, and it seems like no event handler is needed for the button if I didn't understand incorrectly.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, 'Enable dismissal of an alert via JavaScript:$(".alert").alert('close')'. In the javascript page not components

Comment: Yep, and some lines down you have an example markup which works ... You should rather read the component documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

Comment: It works because 'data-dismiss="alert"', I am just wondering if it's possible to using javascript only.

Comment: yep ... just go for any provided answer here, which attaches an eventhandler to the button which calls `alert('close')`, and you're all set ...

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer you are looking for, although do you mind if I ask why you don't want to use `data-dismiss="alert"`?

```
$('div.alert .close').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().alert('close'); 
});
```

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9JLSW/1/)

Comment: I am using `data-dismiss="alert"`, just curious about the javascript way bootstrap [document](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts) mentioned

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this.

```
/* Fadeout Flash Notice */
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert').fadeOut('slow');}, 3000
  );
```

Comment: umm whats wrong with this? and rather than just mark down the answer it is always courteous to give a reason why you think this is not right for you

Comment: ok...have you tried the code, with this the alert will just fade out giving the user nothing to do, just change the timing to suit your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script>
$('.close').click(function(){
    $("div.alert").hide();

});
</script>
```

Comment: @Harrison---have you checked above code?what is wrong in this..alert will hide when you click on close (x)...this is jquery ..?

Comment: I didn't mark you down. I am curious about why someone marked my question down as you do.

Comment: your question is clear to me and i gave solution .I didn't mark you down....-Harrison

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9JLSW/57/

The code looks like this:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div class="alert alert-success addDefinitionMessage alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <span>12345</span>
</div>
```

If you want to hide the alert in the beginning, you can add an inline css as :

```
    <div id="a"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-success addDefinitionMessage alert-dismissable" style="display:none">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <span>12345</span>
        </div>
```

and the show the alert using jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.alert').show();
});
</script>
```